# Geoip2 asks for gpg secret key

Tags: geolocation, gnupg

I am trying to use geoip2 locally. I have NO gpg installed. I get "gpg: no default secret key: Unusable secret key". Should I install gpg first? What else may be missing?

Comment: GeoIP2 is just a database. Are you trying to install one of the APIs? If so, which one?

Comment: Do you have SSL installed in your machine? I believe the API required cryptographic library installed first.

Comment: The API is geoip2-0.7.0.jar, maxminddb-0.2.0.jar
Not sure if it needs ssl as it explicitly asks for GPG (not for PGP 8-). I think I have some ssl on my machine (Win 7) as it is able to read https. Will try to install GPG ...